# How do I attach a file when the input.file has a dynamic id?

Tags: ruby, file-upload, cucumber, capybara

I have run into a snag with dynamic ids. The attach_file command needs the id name of the input type="file".  The problem is that the id is dynamic

```
(id="document_22") #indicating the 22nd document uploaded to this section.
```

Is there a way to get the id of an element?  something like...

```
attach_file(find(:xpath, ".//input[@name='file_upload']").get('@id'),
'C:\\Users\\testbox\\Documents\\testdoc.xls')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[attach_file](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method) internally just passes filename to `Capybara::Node::Element#set` method.

So you can use:

```
find(:xpath, ".//input[@name='file_upload']").set(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attribute of an element by doing:

```
element['attribute_name']
```

So for your example, to get the id attribute of the input with name 'file_upload', you can do:

```
find(:xpath, ".//input[@name='file_upload']")['id']
#=> "document_22"
```