# Capybara testing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, carrierwave, cocoon-gem

I have models `Post` and `Image`. `Post` has_many `images`

I have this field

`<%= f.file_field :image, required: false %>`

How to test adding image that is adding by `cocoon` gem methods with Capybara attach_file method?

`attach_file( "file_field", "#{Rails.root}/spec/assets/example.jpg" )`

What should I write instead of `file_field`? What is the name of this field should be? "image" or :image don`t work.

According to Capybara docs: "The file field can be found via its name, id or label text." But none of the above is working.

Comment: Use `save_and_open_page` to open the page in your browser and the use the web inspector to find the name, id or label.

Comment: could you add the html generated of your file field?

Comment: You provide very little info for us to guess what the id/name/label of the field could be. Can you show us a little more to get an impression how your entire form/view code looks? Which form-builder are you using? Does your file-field have (a correct) label? Or show us the generated html of the field. Also it is possible to use xpath expressions instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165455/how-do-i-attach-a-file-when-the-input-file-has-a-dynamic-id

Comment: Hi if my answer was useful, please consider select it as accepted answer, that's how the community works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is decision that I found, and it works for me. You search for all input elements on the page and then just setting the value for each.

`elements = page.all(:css, 'input[type="file"]')
 elements[0].set "#{Rails.root}/spec/assets/example.jpg"
 elements[1].set "#{Rails.root}/spec/assets/example_2.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload)

```
it "can upload an image" do
  post :picture, avatar: fixture_file_upload('files/spongebob.png', 'image/png')
  response.should be_success
end
```

Read answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails), I think would be helpful.